# Isssue with Revalidate Itinerary Rest Api

Tags: asp.net, rest, sabre, server-error

```
{
  "type": "SERVER",
  "errorCode": "SEC_DENY",
  "message": "Permission denied because of missing FFOCUS in the user attributes"
},
{
  "type": "SERVER",
  "errorCode": "SEC_DENY",
  "message": "Permission denied because of missing ORGFQD in the user attributes"
}
```

when I call the Revalidate Itinerary Rest APi it shows the above exception with the responseStatusCode: 200.
Anyone kindly help me on it. I don't understand the exception properly and if the responseStatusCode is 200 why response giving me this Exception

I have tried by changing the Authorization token but it didn't helped